# R: How can a function assign a value to a variable that will persist outside the function?

Tags: r, scope, variable-assignment

This is probably easy but I am confused as hell with environments. I would like to use a call to a function to assign a value to a variable, but I need to be able to use that variable after the call. However, I assume, the variable created by the function only exist within the function environment. In short, I need something akin to a global variable (but I am a beginner with R).

The following code :

```
assignvalue = function(varname){
        assign(varname,1)
     }
assignvalue("test")
test
```

returns `Error: object 'test' not found` whereas I would like it to be equivalent to

```
test <- 1
test
```

I read something in the documentation of `assign` about environments, but I could not understand it.

Comment: Why not just to do something like `test <- assignvalue()`?: the function will just create the variable value, and then do the assignment outside it. Safer and cleaner.

Comment: `assign(varname,1,envir=.GlobalEnv)`

Comment: `<-` = local environment, `<<-` next level up. Within a function, if you want a variable pushed into global, use `<<-`

Comment: You can also use the global assign operator `<<-`

Comment: Why do you want to use a function to do this?   That's not really a great idea in any language.

Answer (score 1):

Say `foo` is a parameter of your function. Simply do this:

```
assignvalue <- function(foo) {
        varname <<- foo
}
assignvalue("whatever")
varname
```

The variable `varname` will point out to the value `"whatever"`.

Comment: This answer isn't really correct.  `<<-` assigns in the parent environment, which is not guaranteed to be the global environment.

Comment: You're right, just edited that part. In this particular case, still, `<<-` would be the best solution.

Comment: Usage of `<<-` is almost never a good solution.  Be very careful when you use `<<-`.