# How to apply global variables in this scenario in R

Tags: r, function, global-variables

I have written a function that should make my script more streamlined, however I am having trouble with assigning variables or calling variables. In this case I want `tax_count` to be as if `Domain_count` was written outside the function. I have tried the solution by [R: How can a function assign a value to a variable that will persist outside the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771304/r-how-can-a-function-assign-a-value-to-a-variable-that-will-persist-outside-the) but with no luck.

Here is my function and calling the function:

```
taxonomic_count <- function(tax_count, tax, col_num, data) {
  tax_count <- aggregate(.~tax, data, sum)
  tax_count$count <- rowSums(select(tax_count, col_num:7))
  tax_count <- tax_count %>% 
    select(tax, count)
}
 taxonomic_count(Domain_count, Domain, 2, Data1)
```

Help would be awesome!

Comment: Sorry, not quite clear to me what your end goal is. Do you mean to say that  you want `tax_count` to persist in the (global) environment once `taxonomic_count()` function finishes evaluation? What are you trying to achieve in the long run?

Comment: `tax_count <-  aggregate(.~tax, data, sum)` should run and apply the result to the variable as if `Domain_count <- aggregate(.~Domain, Data1, sum)`

Comment: you need to assign the value from the  function. `tax_count <-  taxonomic_count(Domain_count, Domain, 2, Data1)`